# Generate unique username using first and last name in python

Tags: python

username is lowercase-only and includes first name and last name. If username is longer than 15 characters, it's cutoff at 15 characters. If username is already taken, I have to make it unique.

I tried this but I dont know how to make it unique

```
first_name = input("what is your first name")
last_name = input("what is your last name")
def createUsername(first_name, last_name):
    username = first_name + last_name
    if len(username) > 15:
        username = first_name + last_name[15 - len(first_name)]
```

Comment: Check if the username generated already exists, and append random letters and/or digits until it is unique.

Comment: @Selcuk my code doesnt work when i write first_name + last_name[15 - len(first_name)]

Comment: @Angela last_name[15-len(first_name)] only gets a single character of the last_name variable. If you’re trying to slice it, use the : before the number to get everything up until that place in the string.

Comment: @Angela That's a completely different question.

Comment: `first_name` alone can be more than 15 letters.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like the code snippet below. I’m checking length of first and last, making sure it’s below 15 and if not, append a string of random integers to the end and return the unique username.

```
import numpy as np
def createUsername(first,last):
    if len(first)+len(last)<15:
        return first + last
    else:
        return first+last[:15-len(first)-2]+str(np.random.randint(100))
```

Now that’s not checking to make sure it’s unique in a set of usernames but that should give you a good starting place.

If you really need a unique id and you have a generous username length, you could append a string format of the date and time down to the millisecond i.e. 20200325114535

**Edited to address unique names:**

Here's a code snippet that handles generating unique usernames. For example: this should handle 10000 people named John Doe.

```
import numpy as np

# list_of_usernames = [] # your list of usernames and this is commented out because if you just run this code, it will always define your list of usernames as [] (empty)

def createUsername(first,last, list_of_usernames):

    username = first + last #create a 'base username'

    if len(username) > 15 or username in list_of_usernames: #check if username is greater than 15 characters or if username in list_of_usernames
        username = first+last[:15-len(first)-4]+str(np.random.randint(10000)) #create username first+last+[some random string of numbers]

    # this while loop will continue to check if the username is not in list_of_usernames. Once it's not in that list, it will append the new username and return the username and list. 
    while True:
        if username not in list_of_usernames:
            list_of_usernames.append(username)
            return username, list_of_usernames

        username = first+last[:15-len(first)-4]+str(np.random.randint(10000)) #if username is in the list, generate new username

createUsername('John', 'Doe', list_of_usernames)
```

Comment: What happens if there are two "John Doe"s?

Comment: I was hoping to provide a starting point but I addressed multiple usernames in the edited section above.